# Уровень звука в video html5

Tags: html5

Как можно установить уровень громкости в теге video html5 на 50% при автозапуске?

Comment: вот тут гляньте http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp

Answer (score 3):

Если только одно видео на страничке, можно попробовать вставить в скрипты такой код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
      var a = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]
      a.volume = 0.5
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Следующий код прекрасно работает для множества видео на странице. Даже можно выставить уровень громкости для каждого видео индивидуально:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show(num) {
        var videoEl = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[num];
        videoEl.volume = 0.5;
    }
</script>
```